# Creating JSON shows error Invalid characters found

Tags: json

Hi am trying to create a JSON Object but it shows error invalid characters found this is my JSON.

```
{
    "title":"Biology",
    "content":"Egg period: 4 -6 days \n
           Eggs laid in cracks and crevices of the loose bark on the trunk \n
            Eggs: ovoid or elliptical and dirty white in colour \n
            Adult :Reddish brown in colour",
    "isSubtitle":"N"
  }
```

Please help to fix this and explain the cases of invalid characters in making JSON will be helpful.

Comment: Did you try googling "json validator" or "json lint" instead? We are not a community driven JSON validator.

Comment: @PeeHaa : Using jsonformatter vaildate my json its shows output as Invalid JSON (RFC 4627) , Error:Invalid characters found.[Code 18, Structure 8]

Answer (score 2):

Line breaks in a JSON String must be escaped to `\n`. JSON can take any-Unicode-character-except-"-or--or-control-character. Your JSON should look like this:

```
{
    "title": "Biology",
    "content": "Egg period: 4 -6 days \n Eggs laid in cracks and crevices of the loose bark on the trunk \n Eggs: ovoid or elliptical and dirty white in colour \n Adult :Reddish brown in colour",
    "isSubtitle": "N"
}
```

Try to validate with [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) for the future.

Answer (score 2):

This is an invalid JSON format , content shouldn't have line feed character so you should despecialize it to be `\\n`.
So the valid format is :

```
{
    "title": "Biology",
    "content": "Egg period: 4 -6 days \\n Eggs laid in cracks and crevices of the loose bark on the trunk \\n Eggs: ovoid or elliptical and dirty white in colour \\n Adult: Reddish brown in colour ",
    "isSubtitle": "N"
}
```